# regex replace with textpad

Tags: regex, find-and-replace, textpad

I need to update a dateformat in a large file I have in textpad.

the dateformat is currently mm-dd-yyyy and I need to make it mm/dd/yyyy

each line with a date starts with a D.

like this:
D02-12-2009

I have my regex search portion working fine ^D(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?)?, but the replace is failing when trying to use $1 $2 $3 for my values D$1/$2/$3.  It's replacing with the literal $1, $2, and $3.  I have set textpad to use POSIX regex.

Any ideas how to capture the values and put them into my replace portion?

Answer (score 8):

Please use `\1 \2 \3` instead of `$1 $2 $3`

Find What: `D([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)`

Replace With: `D\1/\2/\3`

Before

```
D02-12-2009
D03-12-2009
D04-12-2009
```

After

```
D02/12/2009
D03/12/2009
D04/12/2009
```

Regarding Grouping

> Groups a tagged expression to use in
>   replacement expressions. An RE can
>   have up to 9 tagged expressions,
>   numbered according to their order in
>   the RE. The corresponding replacement
>   expression is \x, for x in the range
>   1-9. Example: If ([a-z]+) ([a-z]+)
>   matches "way wrong", \2 \1 would
>   replace it with "wrong way".

PS:I have no idea why this is moved to here, I had to come here for the first time. :-)

Comment: I couldn't get `\1` to work in TextPad 7.0.9 only `$1` would work and only if there's two or more groups. Otherwise I had to use `$&`. yuck

Answer (score 0):

*"each line with a date starts with a D."* I would for extra safety add "**^**" to the find expression: `**^**D([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)`.
 Not very likely that the string would occur somewhere else, but...